# why do i get [object Promise]

Tags: javascript

in a request fetch I always find [object Promise]
This is my code:

```
async function getStartChat() {
        const response = await fetch("lib/start_chat.php")
        let data = await response.text();
        return data;
    }

let saveChat = getStartChat();
if(saveChat !== "") qCHAT.innerHTML = saveChat;
```

I also tried this other way:

```js
async function getStartChat() {
        const response = await fetch("lib/bot.php").
        then(response => response.text()).
        then(data => { return data }).
        catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

but I always get the same answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async functions always returns a promise.

if you want to use the value of the result you have to use .then

```
getStartChat().then(saveChat => {
    if(saveChat !== "") qCHAT.innerHTML = saveChat;

});
```